# Twig (Symfony2) doesn't see variable in 'extend' block

Tags: inheritance, symfony, twig

I define variable in controller and pass it to template but it's not visible in `extend` block. The important controller code is:

```
        $response['html'] = $this->renderView(
            'AldenXyzBundle:Profile:edit_ajax.html.twig', array(
                'isXmlHttpRequest' => $request->isXmlHttpRequest(),
            )
        );
```

and Twig template

```
{% extends isXmlHttpRequest ? '::base-ajax.html.twig' : '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

and I have exception `Variable "isXmlHttpRequest" does not exist in ...` while the template

```
{% extends '::base-ajax.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
{{ dump(isXmlHttpRequest) }}
...
{% endblock %}
```

works well and display correct `$isXmlHttpRequest` value.

I also tried directly in template:

```
{% extends app.request.isXmlHttpRequest ? '::base-ajax.html.twig' : '::base.html.twig' %}
```

but I got an exception saying `app is undefined`.

I'm using symfony v2.0.15 and twig v1.8.2

Comment: This feature is available since Twig 0.9.7, can you check what version of twig you're using ?

Comment: Did you try using if statements instead of the conditional operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
{% set layout = app.request.isXmlHttpRequest ? '::base-ajax.html.twig' : '::base.html.twig' %}
{% extends layout %}
```

Comment: Don't know, why this answer is accepted, but if `app` doesn't work in `extends`, how should `layout` work?

Comment: I don't know, why you vote down my answer without testing it? {% extends isXmlHttpRequest ? '::base-ajax.html.twig' : '::base.html.twig' %}` does not work because `extends excepts a string and twig is not parsing correctly.

Comment: works just fine, the problem us using a conditional statement inside the extends statement. By using a variable and setting it before twg is just reading the value of the variable in the extends function rather than trying to perform a function to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem like koral, although the solution given by Besnik for a conditional statement did not work for me. It took me a while to figure out that the reason for this was that I used a combination of a conditional extend  `{% extend ? : %}` plus a form theme `{% form_theme form _self %}`.

So, after implementing the solution given, I still recieved an exception saying the var `app` (or in my case the var `vars`) is undefined. But, for anyone who is facing the same problem: there is a solution:

Create **a Twig function**, In which you can add all your logic and logistics, and use it in your Twig template:

```
{% extends parent_template() %}
```

There is an excelent [post](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2013/02/27/symfony2-more-twig-ajax-templates/) regarding this issue. Also see this [post](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5284) in the symfony forum which mentions the issue.